# CSS styling not working for label inside fieldset

Tags: html, css

so I am trying to style a label with `id=title` inside `fieldset` but for some reason, styling isn't working when the label is inside the `fieldset` but when moved outside the `fieldset`, it works properly.

I am talking specifically about:

```
#title{
    margin-top: 100px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
}

#title::first-letter
{
    font-size: 60px;
    color: brown;
}
```

they are only working when I convert this code:

```
<body>
    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <label id="title">Login Here</label>
        </fieldset>
        

    </form>
</body>
```

into this code:

```
<body>
    <form>
        <fieldset>
           
        </fieldset>
         <label id="title">Login Here</label>

    </form>
</body>
```

---

so this is the intended code:

```css
body{
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    margin: auto;
}

html {
    min-height: 100%;/* fill the screen height to allow vertical alignement */
    display: grid; /* display:flex works too since body is the only grid cell */
}
  
fieldset{
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: white;
    width: 300px;
    text-align: center;
}

form{
    justify-content: center;

    display: flex;
    padding: 20px;

    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);

}

legend > img{
    border-radius: 50%;
}

#title{
    margin-top: 100px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
}

#title::first-letter
{
    font-size: 60px;
    color: brown;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index1.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <label id="title">Login Here</label>
        </fieldset>
        

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

also note that when changing the type from `label` to `p` it worked but IDK why, so any suggestion for the problem?

Comment: `::first-letter` can only be used with block-level elements. Add `label { display: block }` to your CSS and you're good to go. Will probably cause some unwanted spacing/line-feeds, but that's CSS for you...

Comment: ::first-letter can only be used with block-level elements.

Comment: You could also use `fieldset::first-letter` instead of `#title::first-letter`